# FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent not falling back to app switch

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

From what I understand `FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent` will first check the phone's FB settings and then fallback to FB app switch if those are not present. However, my logins are falling back directly to FB's web view. Has anyone encountered this before?

```
FBSession *fbSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"]];
        [FBSession setActiveSession:fbSession];
        [fbSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                  completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: It should definitely not go to webview. It should go to the FB app if installed, and then fallback to Safari. Is it not even going to Safari?

Comment: I think the webview has priority over safari

Comment: Not on iOS, the order is FB app, then Safari. It will never open webview unless you explicitly force it to.